# Gram--Schmidt ortogonalization for complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, orthogonality

I am trying to perform the Gram--Schmidt orthogonalization on a set of continuos complex functions. Numerical solution would be quite sufficient for me.

I have three continuous functions of complex argument on $[0,\pi]$:

$$
f_1(x) = \sin(x) \\
f_2(x) = \sin(2x) \\
f_3(x) = \sin(3x) \\
$$

These are obviously orthogonal and I have checked that my Maple and Octave algorithms confirm that.

However, even a slight detour to the complex plane ruins the final set orthogonality. For example:

$$
f_1(x) = \sin(x - 0.01\mathrm{i}x) \\
f_2(x) = \sin(2x) \\
$$

Then by the modified Gram-Schmidt:

$$
g_1 = \frac{f_1}{\sqrt{\langle f_1,f_1\rangle}} \\
g_2 = f_2 - \langle g_1,f_2\rangle g_1 \\
g_2 := \frac{g_2}{\sqrt{\langle g_2,g_2\rangle}}
$$

where ${\langle r,s \rangle} = \int_0^\pi fg^* \mathrm{d}x$.

Yet only the real part of ${\langle g_1,g_2 \rangle}$ is zero (to the machine precision). The imaginary part is non-vanishing. Since I have tried the same procedure in Maple as well as in Octave obtaining the same results (I mean exactly the same, no implementation bias) I must be missing something more fundamental. Any help and/or hints, please?

Comment: Are you sure you are not just having rounding errors?

Comment: Maybe you just need to change $\langle g_1,f_2\rangle$ to $\langle f_2,g_1\rangle$. The order does matter, but I do not know off the top of my head which order you need here. Recall $\langle x,y\rangle=\overline{\langle y,x\rangle}$.

Comment: @SmileyCraft I cannot fully exclude that but the results in the two mentioned environments match and they do not alter for any computational points refinement. That's suspicious.

Comment: @SmileyCraft YES!!! That was it!